# Google Maps Premium Plan on react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to modify an app which is using react-native-maps with a free API token to start using the "Premium plan" for Google Maps.

I have reviewed the documentation, but I can not find how to add the premium client id and channel id.

Also, after checking https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/android-get-started I saw that for native applications the package "com.google.android.m4b.maps" should be used instead of "com.google.android.gms.maps". How can I do this with react-native-maps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The react-native-maps project has [several dependencies](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/search?q=%22com.google.android.gms.maps%22&unscoped_q=%22com.google.android.gms.maps%22) on `com.google.android.gms.maps`. Unfortunately, you will need to either…

1. Fork this project and update the dependencies to `com.google.android.m4b.maps`, or
2. Write your own [Android Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) for the functionality you need instead of using react-native-maps